# How do you validate against empty form fields in D7?

Tags: forms

In D6, the method I used was to store the value of form fields into a variable and then setting an error message of the variable == null.

Is this still possible in D7, or is there a better way to handle this?  The fields I'm trying to apply custom validation to are select lists so I imagine there must be a different technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out on my own: The process is the same as in Drupal 6. The arrays have just changed a bit. To use a custom validation with `hook_form_alter()` and a custom validation function, you would load your form_state values as follows (example based on fields from profile2):

```
function example_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Store our field values to validate against.
  $fieldname = $form_state['values']['profile']['field_name']['und'][0]['value'];

  if ($fieldname == null) {
    form_set_error('profile][field_name', t('Error Message'));
  }
}
```

The actual value for our fields is now found in the `'und'` array. Since the `#parent` property of these profile fields is an array, use `'foo][foo2'` format to specify the element for which to show the validation error. See [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/7).